# Truncate or drop table command not working on bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

The problem I am facing is that when I execute the deletion query, it appears to be processing the logs but does not actually remove any data from the table. This unexpected behavior has left me puzzled and in need of guidance to resolve the issue.

Here are some additional details:

- Database Type: [Specify the type, e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL]

- Query Executed: [Include the DELETE statement you used]

- Expected Outcome: [Explain what you expected to happen]

- Actual Outcome: [Describe what actually occurred]

I have double-checked the query syntax and permissions, and everything seems to be in order. However, despite my efforts, I cannot seem to make the deletion work as expected.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in troubleshooting this issue. If you could provide any insights, suggestions, or steps to investigate the problem further, it would be immensely helpful.

If you require any additional information or access to the database for a closer inspection, please let me know, and I will be happy to provide it promptly.

Thank you in advance for your support. I look forward to your response and hope we can resolve this matter as soon as possible

Comment: Hello, can you provide an example of the code you're trying to run? it seems like your additional details are empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.